# OleCreateFromFile returns 0x80040154: Class not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, ms-word, ole

Calling [OleCreateFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a *.docx file path returns 0x80040154: Class not registered. This is on a Windows 7 system with Office 2010 installed and Visual Studio 2008, but the issue has been reproduced on a variety of systems and also with Office 2003.

How do I determine which class was attempted to be registered? Calling [GetClassFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the same file path argument results in a valid CLSID for Microsoft Word, which can indeed be instantiated from within the application. An older version of this application with the exact same call to OleCreateFromFile does not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you can relatively easily do is to use [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to trace registry activity between your calling `OleCreateFromFile` API and getting `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` back. You will see queried registry keys, esp. under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and you will be able to follow the attempt of the API to instantiate the object.